# Element-by-element comparison of two vectors of equal length

Tags: r, match

I wish to compare each element between two character vectors that have the same length, using R. I can do this easily with a for loop, but am seeking an alternative method. For example,

```
x<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C")
y<-c("A", "B", "E", "D", "E", "C")

matches<-vector(length=6)

for(i in 1:6){
   matches[i]<-match(x[i], y[i])
}

matches

[1]  1  1 NA  1  1  1
```

This seems so simple but I am having trouble figuring it out.

Thank you

Comment: `x == y` does the elementwise comparison

Answer (score 4):

We can just do `==` to compare both vectors elementwise

```
x == y
```

It returns `TRUE` for a matching value and `FALSE` for non-match

If we need to convert to `1` and `NA`

```
NA^(x != y)
#[1]  1  1 NA  1  1  1
```